# Is there an equivalent of COUNTIF in R?

Tags: r

I have some forestry data I want to work with. There are two variables in question for this portion of the data frame:

1. species
2. status (0 = alive, 2 = dead, 3 = ingrowth, 5 = grew with another tree)

MY GOAL is to count the number of trees that are 0 or 3 (the live trees) and create a tibble with species and number present as columns.

I have tried:

`spp_pres_n <- plot9 %>% count(spp, status_2021, sort = TRUE)`

Which gives a tibble of every species with each status. But I need a condition that selects only status 0 and 3 to be counted. Would if_else or a simple if statement then count suffice?

Comment: `cumsum(status %in% c(0, 3))`? That gets the cumulative count of values of 0 or 3

Answer (score 1):

A simple way with `dplyr`

```
plot9 %>%
  filter(status_2021 %in% c(0,3)) %>% 
  count(spp, status_2021, sort = TRUE)
```